# I want to know how to send 5 strings in Android to Arduino to store in variable?

Tags: android, arduino

I've used Amarino receive 5 String on Android from 5 edittexts then send to Arduino.

```
//Code to send a String.  One of five Strings.
Amarino.sendDataToArduino(MainActivity.this,"HC-05",'a',name);
```

In Arduino I've created functions for each String for save in variables.  But I can't pass compiling.  There is  an error messages "void value not ignored as it ought to be" .

```
//Arduino code.  I take part of custom function code that relate Meetandroid.
void getUsername(byte flag, byte numOfValues)
{
  // first we need to know how long the string was in order to prepare an array 
  // big enough to hold it.
  // you should know that: (length == 'length of string sent from Android' + 1)
  // due to the '\0' null char added in Arduino
  int length = meetAndroid.stringLength();

  // define an array with the appropriate size which will store the string
  char data[length];

  // tell MeetAndroid to put the string into your prepared array
  //Can't compile Here
  username = meetAndroid.getString(data);
}
```

I've also tried to send array of String.  There is a function in Amarino but I can't find the receive function.  I dont know what I may miss.  How to solve this problem?

```
//data is array of String in Andriod
Amarino.sendDataToArduino(MainActivity.this,"HC-05",'a',data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`meetAndroid.getString(data)` has no return value. Thus, you can't assign it to `username`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char data[length];

username = meetAndroid.getString(data);
```

Change that to:

```
char data [] = new char[length];

meetAndroid.getString(data);

String username = data.toString();

return username; // and change function return type to String
```

You are sure `byte data [] = new byte[length];` isn't more appropriate?

Comment: I think you thought it's Java but it's Arduino C.  I've looked at a book. "new" in C relates pointer. There is no toString in Arduino C.  And the relate function is forced to use void in custom function.  For byte I think I want to store something like name I think it should be the letter not digit.